# popen & poll for output

Tags: c, process, popen

We are using popen and poll with timeout for reading output from a process.

I have a case where we with popen start ssh that creates a reverse tunnel and moves to background.
Ssh probably forks a process to bacground and stops the calling process.

Now my popen does not complete on feof but it waits till timeout. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? In the likes when calling process exits we do not wait for output of a child?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that you use [`poll(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)? If so, are you checking for `POLLHUP` in `revents`?

Comment: I use:  struct pollfd pfd = { fileno(pipe), POLLIN, 0 }; ret = poll(&pfd, 1, timeout);

Comment: @TedLyngmo i added struct pollfd pfd = { fileno(pipe), POLLIN | POLLHUP, 0 }; but still i can see in the output of getline that the child of ssh process finished and went into background but the command stays on poll. My command call is  ssh -fo ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -i /root/.ssh/dropbear_ecdsa_host_key -y -N -f -R remote_port:127.0.0.1:22  user@some_ip -p some_port

Comment: Ok, did you set the file descriptor in non-blocking mode?

Comment: I'm thinking, something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/s8Wor5b4P)

Comment: no poll is in blocking mode, why would it need to be in nonblock ? It has a timeout and if timeout occurs return = 0 if error anykind return -1, but the catch is that poll always returns with = 0 timeout.

Comment: No, non-blocking shouldn't be necessary but it's often easier to see where things hang. If it always returns by timeout the process started by `popen` haven't closed its `stdout`. If you show a [mre] it'll be easier to see if you've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @TedLyngmo https://godbolt.org/z/obPP57Pav

Comment: It's better if you put the code in the question so that it's clearly visible to everyone interested in answering. It's a C++ program though, so you might want to change the language tag too. I added [some checks](https://godbolt.org/z/EzedYPqq8) and a loop to your program. Perhaps that'll work better.

Comment: I think the problem is that POPEN waits also for all the childs that started process starts. For example the ssh command i start forks to background eg. never completes in my time frame, as it was intended. So is there a way to instruct popen, close pipe when starting process exits.

Comment: `popen` creates a `pipe()`, then `fork()`s and then executes `/bin/sh -c "your command"`. When opening a `pipe` for reading, the writing end of the `pipe` will stay open until closed by started process and all subprocesses that may have `dup`ed it. You'd have to somehow close it on the "ssh" side of the `popen`. `popen` can't know otherwise. You could however implement a `popen` version yourself using `pipe`s, `fork` and `exec*`. You could then monitor the `pid_t` returned by `fork` in addition to the `pipe`s.